# What are some of the most common structures for lyrics?

Tags: structure, lyrics

More specifically, what are the repeating parts usually in popular songs, and where do we put them normally? I want to write the lyrics for a popular song, but I am not sure how to structure them.

There are five elements, namely: intro, verse, pre-chorus, chorus, bridge.

What are the repeating parts, and where do should I place them in a song?

Comment: Hi, if you'd like us to consider adding new tags, please post the suggestion in Writing Meta.

Comment: I know I answered your question, but an album that I love that really plays with song structure and lyricism is Hawaii Pt. 2 by Miracle Musical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most common formats for songs is **Verse 1, Chorus, Verse 2, Chorus, Bridge, Chorus.**

Most verses follow a simple **ABAB or ABCB** rhyme format - that is, in ABAB, the first and third lines rhyme and the second and fourth lines rhyme, and in ABCB, the second and fourth lines rhyme but the first and third do not.

With choruses, also called refrains, a **hook** is usually included at both the beginning and the end.  Choruses are also sang in a different range than the rest of the verses, to provide variety.

A bridge is played in a different chord, and the lyrics may say something previously unexplored, or deeper in meaning than the verses.

Of course, this is not the only format for songs.  Some songs have a more complex structure, such as **Intro, Verse 1, Pre-Chorus, Chorus, Verse 2, Pre-Chorus, Chorus, Bridge, Chorus x2, Outro.**  Some songs do not even have a chorus, or a rhyme scheme.  Some songs don't need it.

Simpler formulas are usually seen in shorter pop songs.  This doesn't mean the song is bad!  Adding your own embellishments to common formulas, or creating your own formula, is how your song becomes your own.  Experiment with what you like and choose what makes the music and your words flow the best.

Comment: Any other format? This is the type of answer I wanted to get.

Comment: @repomonster Added more to the answer!  Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's going to be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: not a songwriter, I do like writing poetry so kind of close but not completely.

From my experience of listening to songs and writing song-like poetry, the repeating parts are typically in the pre-chorus and the chorus. The intro, the bridge, and each verse are all separate entities that are connected via theme and subject. However, they don't use the same words. Usually they tend to use the same chord progression and melody, but that also depends on the song. Each section definitely uses different lyrics though.